# Hourglass control in shear part for shell (ABAQUS)

Tags: shell, matrix, integration, abaqus, hourglass

I am trying to take into account the "hourglass" effect in the shear part when composing the finite element stiffness matrix using selective reduced integration.

I am relying on this article from the theoretical manual of ABAQUS:
https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/2009/spring/mase5513/abaqus/docs/v6.6/books/stm/default.htm?startat=ch03s02ath63.html#stm-elm-incompatible

Go to item 3.6.5 in the menu when clicking on the link and scroll down to the chapter: One-point integration plus stabilization

The matrices Bd and Br are responsible for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoT63.png)

But my stiffness matrix is the same as the matrix from the ABAQUS only for a square element of size 2x2. For a square element of a different size, the matrix also coincides with the ABAQUS, if I multiply the entire matrix Bd by 2/a, where a is the side of the element.

But I can't get the matrices to match for a rectangular element with different side lengths.
And it also doesn't work for a rhomb.

Can the coefficients of Г change in this case?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHAx0.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Readers can only help fix code that they can see. (Don't post, let alone link to images). Please read about [mcve] and use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.